# Chrome offline wont use cache.manifest

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, cache-manifest

Since the last updates of Chrome, I can't access to an offline page even if the cache.manifest is correctly "installed" (I checked chrome://appcache-internals).

I also checked if the system worked on iOS and Android (Chrome) devices, it works fine...

So, can you confirm (or not) that it is a Chrome (desktop) bug ?

**Edit :**

When I visit the page, I see the logs of cache.manifest loadings... all succeed.
Just after, if I visit chrome://appcache-internals, the cache.manifest is in the list.
But, if I go back to the site, toggle chrome to offline mode then reload, the message "no connection" is showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... unfortunately, Google don't make distinguish between "cache manifest" and the standard "cache" so in the DevTools, unselect "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)".

My bad...